# printing the result of a grep and the code of curl

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I would like to get all the urls from a large file, and check the status of that link online. So, for example, I'd like to have

stackoverflow.com, 200 OK
...

So far I have `grep -o "https?:*" file.txt | xargs curl -IsN 2>&1 | grep HTTP`, but I don't know how to show the url `grep` is feeding `xargs` and `curl` is visiting.`, but this only returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
```

Comment: show the content of your `file.txt`

Comment: @Kent: the grep works fine, I'm just after how to print the url that is going into curl after xargs

Comment: Do you have URLs one per line in your file.txt?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
grep  "https:" file.txt | xargs -I {} curl -I  -L -s -o /dev/null -w "%{url_effective},%{response_code}" {}
```

I am wondering if your `grep` is really capturing the whole URL since you used the `-o` parameter. Have you tested the `grep` command alone ?

Note that in this example I added the `-L` parameter to automatically follow redirections, and I am using [cURL variables](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-verbose/usingcurl-writeout) to fetch the last response code (`%{response_code}`) and the final URL (`%{url_effective}`) after redirection. But if you'd like you can show the original URL from the file, rather than the final URL as shown by `curl`.

Most of the time, going to domain.com implies a redirect to www.domain.com. So the first request returns a 301 or 302 response code, and the second request returns 200 (if all goes well). There may be multiple redirects and even redirect loops on misconfigured websites. So what we are normally interested in is the last response code.

Then, using `xargs`, you could add parallel processing. I assume this is what you had in mind since you said you have a large file.